# Scheduled tasks for running scripts using node won't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, scheduled-tasks

I followed this tutorial for scheduling a task for running a script using node:

https://eddyerburgh.me/run-a-node-script-with-windows-task-scheduler

I left my pc turned on so it could execute the script, but when i came to see if it did execute, there was only a cmd.exe instance open and the task didn't execute the script.

Here's how i configured the action:

```
Program/Script - C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe

Arguments - --a -i -c "cd C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\folder; node script.js"
```

Is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 6):

You don't need all those extra arguments. Just use the following settings:

**Program/Script:** `node` (or `"C:\\Proram Files\node\node.exe"` if it's not in your PATH)
**Arguments:** `C:\\Users\user\folder\script.js`

It will work.

[image]

Comment: i followed your instructions but my script is not executing.do i need to use forward slashes or backward in arguments field?

Comment: @Naeem did you manage to make it work? I think it's not working on windows 10 due to privilege issues...

Comment: node is in my path but I still needed to specify the path to node.exe (I browsed to find it), then it worked though I put the file to run in the arguments field (index.js) and the start in field had the directory the file is in

Answer (score 5):

I've managed to make it work by making a .bat file like this:

```
if not "%minimized%"=="" goto :minimized
set minimized=true
@echo off
cd "<folder where the script is">

start /min cmd /C "node <the script you want to execute>"
goto :EOF
:minimized
```

Then you can schedule the .bat file to be executed.

Comment: Scheduling a batch is definitely the way to go.